# How to use "ga:isoWeek" in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I need to have this year data by week from GA4.
I used the below API:

```
  {
    "dateRanges": [{ "startDate": "2021-1-1", "endDate": "yesterday" }],
    "dimensions": [
      {
        "name": "week"
      }
    ],
    "metrics": [{ "name": "activeUsers" }]
}
```

But, I’d like to have the week from Monday to Sunday as ISO week, instead Sunday to Saturday.

I have known UA had "ga:isoWeek" as dimensions, but how about GA4?

Answer (score 1):

Ga4 does not support isoWeek at this time.  You should check out the [API Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema)  for the Google analytics data api it shows all the dimensions and metrics that work with GA4.

[image]

Comment: I have known Ga4 does not support isoWeek at this time, but I still need the solution to have this year data by week from Monday to Sunday~.~

Comment: Download it as google analytics gives it to you and convert it locally.   You can only download what Google analytics api supplies.     If they dont give you that option then you cant do it you the developer need to find a work around to solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm not the only one who has been waiting for this: isoWeek was finally added to the dimensions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema